# How to get pandas MultiIndex's values in the form of a list?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex. I want to get a list which includes MultiIndex `level0` and `level1` like this `[level0,[level1-1,level1-2,(...)]`.

For example:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays,columns=['values'])
df
```

out:

```
           values
bar one  2.171200
    two -0.665047
baz one  0.474036
    two  0.082408
foo one  1.820585
    two  0.698537
qux one  1.163479
    two  0.129044
```

I want to output a dataframe like this:

```
      output
bar  ['one','two']
baz  ['one','two']
foo  ['one','two']
qux  ['one','two']
```

How? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `list`:

```
df1 = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby('level_0')['level_1']
        .apply(list)
        .rename_axis(None)
        .to_frame('output'))
```

Or [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) (new in pandas 0.20.0+):

```
df1 = df.index.to_frame().groupby(0)[1].apply(list).rename_axis(None).to_frame('output')
print (df1)

         output
bar  [one, two]
baz  [one, two]
foo  [one, two]
qux  [one, two]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor and then use `groupby`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.index.values.tolist(), columns=['idx1', 'idx2'])\
        .groupby('idx1')['idx2'].apply(list)

print(res)

idx1
bar    [one, two]
baz    [one, two]
foo    [one, two]
qux    [one, two]
Name: idx2, dtype: object
```